# Turbulenz: How bound a physics node to a scene node

Tags: javascript, typescript, game-engine, scene, turbulenz

How can I bound a physics node to a scene node?

Since the documentation reads that when an update is made to the physics node its propagated to the scene node I assume that the transformation matrix of the scene node is updated also. Is this correct?

For instance, I have the following scene:

```
this.scene =  Scene.create(this.devices.mathDevice);
this.sceneLoader.load({
        scene         : this.scene,
        append        : false,
        assetPath     : "models/duck.dae",
        keepCameras   : true,

        baseMatrix: this.devices.mathDevice.m43BuildTranslation(0, 100, 0),

        graphicsDevice: this.devices.graphicsDevice,
        mathDevice    : this.devices.mathDevice,

        textureManager: this.managers.textureManager,
        effectManager : this.managers.effectManager,
        shaderManager : this.managers.shaderManager,

        requestHandler: this.requestHandler,
        dynamic       : true
    });
```

and the following physics node:

```
       var ballShape = this.devices.physicsDevice.createSphereShape({
            radius: 1.0,
            margin: 0.001
        });

        var mass = 20;
        var inertia = ballShape.inertia;
        inertia = this.devices.mathDevice.v3ScalarMul(inertia, mass);
        var ballObject = this.devices.physicsDevice.createRigidBody({
            shape      : ballShape,
            mass       : mass,
            inertia    : inertia,
            transform  : this.scene.findNode("LOD3sp").getLocalTransform(),
            friction   : 0.5,
            restitution: 0.3,
            frozen     : false,
            group      : this.devices.physicsDevice.FILTER_DYNAMIC,
            mask       : this.devices.physicsDevice.FILTER_ALL
        });
        this.dynamicsWorld.addCollisionObject(ballObject);
```

But I don't know how to link them together so when the physics ball node falls from height the model also falls down.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created an utility function to pass it the variables and do the binding, is:

```
public bindPhysicsNodesWithSceneNodes(options):void {
    var physicsNode = {
        body   : options.rigidBody,
        target : options.sceneNode,
        dynamic: true
    };

    options.sceneNode.physicsNodes = [physicsNode];
    options.sceneNode.setDynamic();

    options.physicsManager.physicsNodes.push(physicsNode);
    options.physicsManager.dynamicPhysicsNodes.push(physicsNode);
    options.physicsManager.enableHierarchy(options.sceneNode, true);
}
```